# How to convert .ass & .ssa subtitles files fomats to webvtt format in js?

Tags: javascript, webvtt, video-subtitles

I know how to transform .srt file format to webvtt format in javascript , I want to know how to do the same with .ass & .ssa subtitles files formats to be able to parse them and transform to webvtt format on the fly without using file stream using javascript .

Comment: Do you have the .ass files as a source? Why don't you want to use some parser  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ass-parser or https://www.npmjs.com/package/ass-to-vtt And if you need just a text and timestamps and don't need fancy features like colors, fonts, position, etc. it could be extracted quite easy. I'm not sure what do you mean 'on the fly'. Line by line? Or just without saving an output files?

Comment: ass-to-vtt uses file stream and I want to get it done on the fly as stated in the question, i send xhr request to grab the text from a file and store it in a string. ass parser doesn't transform .ass to .srt or .webvtt directly .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a deep search I found what I asked for in an underrated Github repo online named subsrt, can be found [here](https://github.com/papnkukn/subsrt) for whoever encounters the same request or similar. it transforms between the following subtitles formats :

MicroDVD SUB (.sub),
SubRip (.srt),
SubViewer (.sbv),
WebVTT (.vtt),
SubStation Alpha (.ssa and .ass),
SAMI (.smi) aka Synchronized Accessible Media Interchange,
LRC (.lrc) aka LyRiCs,
JSON (.json)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to convert YouTube-created `.sbv` captions to WebVTT.